# Conditional formating of excel row based on the value of the first cell of the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to apply a conditional formating for a row only if the first cell (`A` column) contains text starting with `Volum`. Is there a way to do such a thing ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, `Applies To` I have set to `=$A$1:$J$5`

Case **In**sensitive: `=LEFT($A1,5)="Volum"`

[image]

Case Sensitive: `=EXACT(LEFT($A1,5),"Volum")`

[image]